# How can I ensure type hints still work for my class that inherits UserList from collections?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a class that adds something on top of standard list behavior. To avoid re-implementing everything, I used `UserList`:

```
from collections import UserList
            
class MyList(UserList):
    ...stuff...
```

But now, when I do something like:

```
my_list = MyList([1,2,3,4])
```

My IDE just marks this as a `MyList` type and hints for things like loops don't work:

```
for an_int in my_list:
    # here, IDE does not know an_int is an int
```

I can force override this, but at the cost of losing hinting for my custom methods by using the type comment:

```
my_list = MyList([1,2,3,4]) # type: list[int]
```

Is there something I can hint in the class definition that will tell python static analysis that the inner type is inherited from the list passed in ctor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify a `TypeVar` parameter indicating the type that `MyList` is generic over:

```
from collections import UserList
from typing import TypeVar

_T = TypeVar('_T')
            
class MyList(UserList[_T]):
    pass

my_list = MyList([1,2,3,4])
reveal_type(my_list)     # Revealed type is "MyList[builtins.int]"
reveal_type(my_list[0])  # Revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

If you add methods that involve the items contained in the list, `_T` is used within the class definition to refer to the type of those items.

If `_T` is specified with a bound, you can limit the acceptable types for a `MyList` to contain; otherwise `_T` can be associated with any particular type at the time that you declare a given `MyList` instance.

Comment: Oh well :( I found this, to my surprise, in my own code from personal project, but what I'm working on runs in python 3.4 and with that I get an error `TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable` I tried to work around that by using `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING` and assigning `UserListBase = UserList[T]` but that does not work at all. It should, IMO, but it is not understood by VS Code.

Comment: Maybe try multiple inheritance with `UserList` and `Generic[_T]`?  Or upgrade from Python 3.4, which is already past official end-of-life...

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably accept this answer anyways. It is the correct one and works fine. I'll try the workaround with generic, but I guess I might be out of luck.

Comment: `class MyList(UserList, Generic[T]):` works even in python 3.4. You might include it in the answer in case another poor soul has to work with that :)

Comment: awesome, I was totally guessing with that suggestion.  XD